# yolo output and how to define labels for backpropogation on it

Tags: deep-learning, backpropagation, object-detection

I want to build the yolo architecture in keras but can't understand the basic idea behind the training of the yolo, like how to define the labels for whether there is no object there what we have to do. Do we have to take the boundary box as 0 or not include the block only for that part? It's quite confusing.